# How to set keycloak to give new access token ONLY via refresh token

Tags: token, keycloak

After getting first access token (and refresh also) with user login and password I need them to no longer be available to get access token. It has to be done only with refresh token every time. Is it possible in Keycloak?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you want that?

Comment: For security. User, who already got access token, doesn't need login and password anymore, but someone, who accidentaly gets them, can get new token and access to service.
I decided to get first access token by myself and give it to user without giving login and password. It's suitable solution for me.

Comment: Basically, you want to avoid a user from having multiple sessions in KC simultaneously, i.e., two people having requested an access token simultaneously for the same client. Is this a pattern that you have seen somewhere? because it looks a bit unorthodox

Comment: Yes, I need users not to get access token via credentials every time, but via refresh token. It's the task I was given :)